# Unable to get Azure DevOps events through REST API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to get Azure DevOps events through REST API listed below:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/notification/events?api-version=5.0-preview.1
```

I tried the above API to get events but in postman call, I am getting below response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "The feature is disabled. Contact your Azure DevOps Server administrator.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.FeatureDisabledException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server",
    "typeKey": "FeatureDisabledException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}
```

It should give events after postman call

Comment: The API you're calling is a POST operation which will publish an event, but your question states that you want to *get* events. I think you're calling the wrong API.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/events/publish%20event?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Your method with POST is for publish a new event: [Events - Publish Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/events/publish%20event?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0). I can not find the get method for events (only: [Event Types - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/event%20types/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) or [Event Types - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/notification/event%20types/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)). Maybe it was not coded yet:

[image]